# How can I convert the following discrete function to continuous?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

I am not a math graduate but have a fair bit of understanding of mathematics from my engineering graduation, I do re-creational mathematics, and ended up having a problem that I think am not knowledgeable enough to solve.

I have a function, which is discrete $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{x-1} 3^{n} $ from $ f: Z+ => Z+ $. How can I make this into a continuous function (I guess it must be an integral). I don't mind slight errors, approximations should do.

Initially, I thought it was just changing the summation to integral, but later I understood that it's not the case.

Can someone help, with an explanation? I want a function $ f: R+ => R+ $. I don't mind if the function gets defined from R-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By geometric series: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3^x-1)$$For positive integer $x$. However, using the same formula for any real number $x$ will provide a continuous extension in a natural way.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get this ?

Comment: Do you know about geometric series?

Comment: Yes I do, a series which increases by a factor of r. (r being any constant)

Comment: Oh this is the formula for sum of geometric series, go it

Answer (score 2):

Your given Discrete function $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{x-1} 3^{n}$ which is a Summation over a Geometric Progression.

We can evaluate that to get :
$f(x) = \frac{3^{x}-1}{2}$

We can now let $x$ be a real number to get the Continuous function which will match the Original Discrete function at all Positive Integral Values.

What it looks like at Positive Integral Values & at all real values :

[image: Power Summation]

Comment: Can you explain how did you get this ?

Comment: More Details : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series !!!